# Is this an appropriate use of generics?

Tags: java, generics

Is it really necessary to use the 'extends BoardGame'?

If I remove it my code still works, but I'm not sure if I should.

I'm doing that because of the copy() method.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

```
public interface BoardGame<GAME extends BoardGame>
{
    GAME getGame();

    BoardGame<GAME> copy();

    int currentPlayer();

    boolean isGameOver();

    int getTotalMoves();

    BoardResult getOutcome(int playerIndex);

    void makeMove(int moveIndex);

    void addMoveObserver(BoardGameMoveObserver observer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are ok in a sense that they compile ok.

If you use `<GAME extends BoardGame>` than all implementations will need to use type parameter that extends BoardGame. This makes sense if any of the methods takes parameter or returns value that is GAME.

In your case that is `getGame()`. So in case of `<GAME extends BoardGame>` all users of of `getGame()` can count that return value is (at least) BoardGame. But in the case of , `getGame()` could return any type the implementing class defined..

Comment: The point to make is that Generics don't get you anything in this case. If you want the benefit of getting the subclass type from the copy method, you have to have a reference to a variable that is of that subtype. You can do that without generics and your code is much cleaner.

Comment: Not quite. With generics implementation of 'getGame()' must return 'GAME', where without generics 'BoardGame' would suffice.

Comment: Good point, though I'd argue the added level of complexity easily offsets the marginal benefit of forcing the return type. A class that implements BoardGame would be perverse to return a different implementing class for this method (and Javadoc should make the expected behaviour clear).

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `copy()` return type be `GAME`?

Generics is never "necessary". We lived without it for a decade and it was fine.

When generics create too much complexity, it's ok to remove some of it. In your case, if it's not generic, you can always document that `copy()` should return a particular type, and the callers can always manually cast the returned object to the specific type. That may prove to be simpler than adding this type parameter, just for a little gain.

P.S. It should have been, to be strict,

```
public interface BoardGame<GAME extends BoardGame<GAME> >
```

Comment: Yes, getGame returns 'this', which I use it for the evaluation function of a specific board game, which is supposed to have access to the actual board game.

Comment: The thing is that I have this general Board Game Interface for a few games, Tic Tac Toe, Othello, Checkers, etc. I have the basic algorithms for such games, minimax with alpha beta pruning, random players, monte carlo tree search, etc. These algorithms make use of all the methods, with the exception of getGame(). The problem is that these algorithms use an EvaluationFunction (interface), which is game specific, that is why I use getGame(), so the specific evaluation function for a game can have access to the actual board.

Comment: not totally understand your description of the problem. but in general, you can relax the bound, i.e. remove the "extends" part. but if you make a mistake, like passing `String` as `GAME`, compiler may not be able to help you immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If the copy method is returning an object that implements BoardGame, you don't have to use generics - it's implicit in the interface definition (and the java language in general) that a return type is the 'lowest common denominator' class. Methods can return an object of that class (or that implements the interface) OR a subclass of the return type.